# Javascript- how to move an image to a canvas in photoshop automatically?

Tags: javascript, canvas, photoshop

I need to use Javascript to create a blank canvas in photoshop and add opened image to a specific location on that canvas (by using Javascript not move the image around manually)

I tried this code:

```
//create canvas
var canvas= app.documents.add(5000,5000,72);
var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');

var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder to process");
var fileList = inputFolder.getFiles();

//open file and auto contrast it
for (var i = 0, len = fileList.length; i < len; i++){
    var i = 1;
    var filename = fileList[i].name;
    var img = app.open(File(inputFolder + "/" + filename));
    img.activeLayer.autoContrast(); 
}
```

An error appears at `canvas[0].getContext('2d')`. It said the `get.Contec`t function does not exist. 
I also tried `canvas = elem.find('canvas')[0]` and `var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')` earlier, none of them work.

Does anyone know where it get wrong?

Comment: You're declaring a variable named `i` inside the loop but there is already a variable named `i`. Declaring variables that already exist isn't good, but the worst is that in your code `i` will always have the value 1 so it will make an infinite loop.

Comment: + You are mixing web API and Photoshop scripting API. I don't know well photoshop scripting APIs, but I would be really surprised if it did support the HTMLCanvasElement, and its `getContext` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your looping over the file list wrong. Infinitely wrong. Try something like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
{
    try 
    {
       var doc = open(fileList[i]);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      alert("Failed to open file!");
    }
}
```